# upgarde Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04 error

Tags: apt, upgrade, updates

```
$ sudo do-release-upgrade

Checking for a new Ubuntu release

Get:1 Upgrade tool signature [819 B]                                             
Get:2 Upgrade tool [1,263 kB]                                                    
Fetched 1,264 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                   
authenticate 'bionic.tar.gz' against 'bionic.tar.gz.gpg' 
extracting 'bionic.tar.gz'

Reading cache

Checking package manager
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree        
Reading state information... Done
Hit http://ppa.launchpad.net/umang/indicator-stickynotes/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Ign http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                       
Hit http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                  
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                         
Hit http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                 
Hit http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                         
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [107 kB]    
Hit http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                         
Fetched 107 kB in 0s (0 B/s)                                                     
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done

Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree          
Reading state information... Done
```

Comment: Have you updated your system before doing release-upgrade? If not, run `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: I performed following commands on my ubantu 16.04 $ sudo apt update

$ sudo apt upgrade
$ sudo apt dist-upgrade

$ sudo apt-get autoremove

$ sudo apt install update-manager-core

Finally:
$ sudo do-release-upgrade but didn't work